# List of tuples PySpark Schema

Tags: python, pyspark, schema

What is the correct PySpark Schema for the following? The first return is a list, which I have coded correctly, but the second return is a list of tuples and I am not sure how to write its corresponding Type in one schema.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("Alive", 4)], ["Name", "Number"])


def example(n):
    return Row('Out1', 'Out2')([n + 2, n+4], [(n, n+2), (n, n+4)])


schema = StructType([
    StructField("Out1", ArrayType(IntegerType()), False),
    StructField("Out2", ArrayType(IntegerType(), False), True)])

example_udf = F.udf(example, schema)

newDF = df.withColumn("Output", F.explode(F.array(example_udf(df["Number"]))))
newDF = newDF.select("Name", "Number", "Output.*")
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use second return type as `array(array(integer))`,

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("Alive", 4)], ["Name", "Number"])
def example(n):
    return ([n + 2, n+4], [(n, n+2), (n, n+4)])

schema =StructType([StructField('out1',ArrayType(IntegerType())),StructField('out2',ArrayType(ArrayType(IntegerType())))])

example_udf = F.udf(example, schema)

df.select(example_udf(df.number).alias('s_col')).select('s_col.out1','s_col.out2').show()
+------+--------------+
| out1 |  out2        |
+---+-----------------+
|[6,8] |[[4,6],[4,8]] |
+------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Suresh! Another answer to my question is:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("Out1", ArrayType(IntegerType()), False),
    StructField("Out2", ArrayType(StructType([StructField("_1", IntegerType(), False), StructField("_2", IntegerType(), False)])))])
```